# Capistrano deploy ** Host key verification failed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano

I've followed several suggestions from other sites but to no avail. When I try 
`cap deploy:cold` 
I consistently get "Host key verification failed."

I've tried everything. I've ssh'd from my computer to the remote, removed and readded both keys from known-hosts, cloned from github, set up my public key from both the server and local on github.

What am I missing here?

---

Capfile:
https://gist.github.com/1308243

---

Errors:
https://gist.github.com/1308255

Comment: did you add ssh_options[:forward_agent] = true to deploy.rb?

Comment: i can only point you to this article from github then and see if you can solve it: http://help.github.com/deploy-with-capistrano/

Comment: Can you attach your Capfile and the log from your terminal output?

Comment: Also, I've read that `cap deploy:cold` is somewhat deprecated. I use `cap deploy:setup` to verify that the server is properly set up, then `cap deploy` to test it out.

Comment: Attached output and tried deploy:setup. It worked, but when I do just a straight cap:deploy I get:
https://gist.github.com/1308273

Answer (score 81, accepted):

#### Add to your deploy.rb:

```
ssh_options[:forward_agent] = true
default_run_options[:pty] = true
```

Or log in to the server(s) you are deploying to (as your deploy user) and run:

```
ssh git@github.com
The authenticity of host 'github.com (207.97.227.239)' can't be established.
RSA key fingerprint is **:**:**:.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes
```

Most of the time I see this issue is when github.com in not in your `~/.ssh/known_hosts`

Comment: +1 to adding github to the known host list. this is often the root cause of this problem.

Comment: The same as greg. I added the public key of the server to github but I didn't try connecting to it. `$ ssh git@github.com` was fine.

Comment: It worked. But along with this, I need to generate a key on my server(which is a new one) and add that in github account & its working!

Answer (score 6):

Instead of using a git ssh url which looks like this 
git@github.com:definelabs/urbanairship.git

use a read only url which looks like this
git://github.com/definelabs/urbanairship.git

Comment: doesn't seem to apply any more because there are no read only repo URLs for private repositories

Answer (score 1):

You had mentioned that `cap deploy:setup` worked and `cap deploy` failed. So looks like the error message is not related to the ssh connectivity, and its related to git checkout. It might be because that your git remote server works with key based authentication and the required key is missing in the server.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to

```
ssh_options[:forward_agent] = true
default_run_options[:pty] = true
```

I also needed do [this](https://serverfault.com/a/316100/133493), with below:

```
def add_domain_to_known_hosts(hostname)
  ip_address = "`dig +short A #{hostname}`"
  run "ssh-keygen -R #{hostname}"
  run "ssh-keygen -R #{ip_address}"
  run "ssh-keygen -R #{hostname},#{ip_address}"
  run "ssh-keyscan -H #{hostname},#{ip_address} >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts"
  run "ssh-keyscan -H #{ip_address} >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts"
  run "ssh-keyscan -H #{hostname} >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts"
end
```

Although, it should be noted that PTY's are discouraged by capistrano:
https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano#a-word-about-ptys

Answer (score -1):

One file to get concerned with `~/YOUR_USER_NAME /.ssh/authorized_keys2` on the server. I believe it should contain the public/private key (one of the two, I think private?)

Comment: The `authorized_keys` file on the server should have the text of your **public** key, which is often file `.ssh/id_rsa.pub` on your local machine.